# Salesforce Certification Platform developer 1

Tags: certification, platform-developer-1

On 11th of July I've passed the salesforce platform dev 1 certificate. And few days ago I recieved and email regarding maintenance. I was curious if i need to take the summer maintenance or i need to go for the winter one?

Thanks,
Darko

Comment: That depends which release your certification was awarded against - if it shows SP17 then you will need to take Summer 17 maintenance but if it shows SU17 then you will need to do the Winter 18 maintenence.

Comment: Hey @DaveHumm it says SP17 and i checked on the website it says the following: This exam is required if you earned the Salesforce Certified Platform Developer I credential on or before July 13, 2017.. Deadline for this is March 2018. Is this the first out of 3 releases for the maintenance? After this one I need to take the other two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what about what the website says is confusing as it seems pretty clear, you took it on the 11th which is before the 13th.

As for 1st of 3, it really is irrelevant. You will have to take a release exam every 4 months until you no longer want the credential. Every Spring exam you will have to pay the maintenance fee of $100.00, the rest of the maintenance exams will be free